# Logstash email alerts

Tags: email, message, logstash, alerts

I configured logstash to send email alerts in case there are some combinations of words in the log message. I get the alerts but instead of receiving the message field value in the alert, I get word "@message".
How can I solve this problem?

Here is my logstash config file:

```
root@srv-syslog:~# cat /etc/logstash/conf.d/central.conf
input {
    syslog {
        type => "syslog"
        port => 5144
    }
    tcp {
        type => "cisco_asa"
        port => 5145
    }
    tcp {
        type => "cisco_ios"
        port => 5146
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        bind_host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => "9200"
        protocol => http
    }
    if "executed the" in [message]  {
        email {
            from => "logstash_alert@company.local"
            subject => "logstash alert"
            to => "myemail@company.local"
            via => "smtp"
            body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{@message}"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field name in this case is `message`, not `@message`.

See demo:

```
input {
    generator {
        count => 1
        lines => ["Example line."]
    }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "m1" => "%{message}"
            "m2" => "%{@message}"
        }
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug{}
    }
}
```

In your case, you should just need to fix the one line:

```
body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{message}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @ sign.  The field is message, not @message.